# php array passing to js to control html

Tags: javascript, php, html

Using PHP, I have encoded a table of:
   `<div>$date</div>` tags... representing a calendar.
Below the calendar, I have another div `id='details'` tag that I would like to populate with information corresponding to the calendar `<div>$date</div>` tag the end user clicks. (i.e.):

```
`$eventTitle[$date];`
`$eventDescription[$date];`
`$kaigsRequired[$date];`
```

1) How do I pass these arrays to my `js.onclick` function

2) How do I use js to write back to `<div id='details'>`

3) Or am I going about this all wrong.... What should I study to accomplish this?

I do not expect to be answered with code; I am just at a loss as to what I should study. I have read something about param passing with json and ajax, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Show us what you have tried yet.We are  not providing full answer, We are  here to help you. Not to write full code and all.

Comment: i have tried passing the full array to the js function in many ways; none of them right obviously. Now I am beginning to wonder if a better way would be for me to stay in php. i.e. <div onclick="phpFunction that updates another div tag.">
Thnks for the immediate response; but, being sleep deprived... I will have to follow up with more detail tomorrow. As to what I am trying to accomplish can be seen at www.socohandyman.com -> LOGIN: root -> PASSWORD: toor

Comment: tell me one thing where do you get the array ? is from dynamically fetches from db or it is already present over there?

Comment: The arrays are populated dynamicly from DB upon page load. I actually have four arrays that are fetched upon loading of the page, all four relate to each other sharing the same index...

DateOfEvent[$i];
TitleOfEvent[$i];
DescriptionOfEvent[$i];

Each element of the arrays at $i correspond to a specific event. 
I can't pass the data of a single index because I need to first parse data from multiple indexes before data is displayed.

Comment: Thanks for the support y'all have offered and the many answers I continue to find provided by the community. I have not yet learned the code I need; but, I have found the topic I need to study to achieve this. ...JSON...  I am a new member and am not sure of protocol regarding closed topics; but, will later add a post of a code snippet for anyone it may help.